# How to compute $H_{5+\sqrt{7}}$

Tags: definite-integrals, binomial-coefficients, gamma-function, harmonic-numbers

How to calculate $H_{5+\sqrt{7}}$ where $H_n$ is the nth harmonic number.

If we use the integral representation of harmonic numbers then we have:

$$H_{5+\sqrt{7}}=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{5+\sqrt{7}}-1}{x-1}dx$$

I don't know how to calculate the integral.

But how I can approx the value of $H_{5+\sqrt{7}}$?

Comment: I believe $H_x  = \psi (x + 1) + \gamma$, where $\psi$ is the digamma function and $\gamma$ is the Euler--Mascheroni constant. There are several ways to compute $\psi$.

Comment: @Gary, is there any way to compute the integral?

Comment: There are better integral representations, see http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.9.ii You may use some software to implement them. However, most softwares come with the digamma function implemented in them already. You may also consider Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: What is $n$ in the second expression?

Comment: Now your second expression doesn't make sense, since a sum can't go up to $5+\sqrt{7}$.

Answer (score 0):

What answer do you want?

There is numerical [value](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/i=harmonic+number+of+%285%2Bsqrt%287%29%29): $2.675338453513690479902288408923721418916296445960334$

There is a method how to [approximate the integrals](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/ap-calculus-ab/ab-integration-new/ab-6-2/a/understanding-the-trapezoid-rule).

There is a [recurrence formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Special_values_for_fractional_arguments): $H_x=H_{x-1}+\frac1x$, which together with the expansion
$$
H_x = \frac{\pi^2}6x+\frac{\psi_2(1)}2x^2+\frac{\pi^4}{90}x^3+\ldots
$$
and tables for polygamma functions allows you to approximate the harmonic number.

There is a formula for [rational approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Special_values_for_fractional_arguments) of argument:
$$
{\displaystyle H_{\frac {p}{q}}={\frac {q}{p}}+2\sum _{k=1}^{\lfloor {\frac {q-1}{2}}\rfloor }\cos \left({\frac {2\pi pk}{q}}\right)\ln \left({\sin \left({\frac {\pi k}{q}}\right)}\right)-{\frac {\pi }{2}}\cot \left({\frac {\pi p}{q}}\right)-\ln \left(2q\right)}
$$

Choose any.

Comment: Could you add that this works for $p<q$ ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is mathematically correct, but it'll still provide a good approximation. A (fairly) smooth curve of $\operatorname{H}(x)$ seems to be defined by:
$$\operatorname{H}\left(x\right)=\frac{\operatorname{mod}\left(x,1\right)}{x}+\operatorname{H}\left(\lfloor{x}\rfloor\right)$$
for all real $x\geq 1$, where $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is the floor function. For the purpose of $\operatorname{mod}\left(x,1\right)$ gives the fractional part of $x$, and the division by $x$ allows the growth rate of that portion of the equation to decay just as quickly as that of $\operatorname{H}\left(\lfloor{x}\rfloor\right)$. Even if this isn't correct, it'll give the decent approximation of $2.67731598605..$ which is exactly $\frac{363}{140}+\frac{\operatorname{mod}\left(\sqrt{7},1\right)}{\sqrt{7}}$.